# London's topology school or London Topology school?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

> 1. London's topology school
> 2. London Topology school

My question contains two facts:

1. Should I write topology with the capital letter?
2. Should I put 's ?

Comment: The London school of topology, and you are referring to a group of academics within an academic debate, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if the *actual name* of the school is "*London Topology School*" then absolutely use that and capitalise it appropriately!

Otherwise if you are just using these words to *describe* a school that you are then going on to name the difference would be whether or not it was the *only* school of topology in London.

"**London's topology school**" would imply that London only has one topology school.

"**London topology school**" does not imply that there is only one such school, merely that the school you are about to refer to is a school of topology in London.

Examples:

> London tourist attraction Madame Tussaud's has a new exhibit.

This is acceptable because Madame Tussaud's is not London's only tourist attraction.

> London's most famous waxwork museum Madam Tussaud's has a new exhibit.

This is correct because by using the determiner "*most*" you are specifically singling the attraction out as the most famous waxwork museum in London.

Let's say you wanted to describe a school as *the top* (or best) topology school in London. You could write either:

> London's top topology school [name of school]

or

> Top London topology school [name of school]

Answer (score 1):

You should use *the name that the school calls itself*.  I can't find a "London School of Topology" but I do see a:

> [London School of Geometry and Number Theory](http://www.lsgnt-cdt.ac.uk/)

Note that it's *London* not *London's*.  The possessive is not typical, but it does show up here and there, notably in:

> **King's** College, Cambridge

Note also that, typically, *all the words are capitalized* except the short *linking* words like "of", "and", "at", etc.